# parse tab delimited file on Mac and PC

Tags: javascript

I haven't done much scripting before.  I took a Javascript class once, but that was mainly for form validation.  I have a tab-delimited file that I want to parse, just taking certain columns I need, not all of them.  I was wondering if there is a good common language to do this in that would work on both the PC or Mac.  I don't know if I need to worry about how each platform interprets newlines or other ASCII characters.  Thanks!

Comment: JS won't help, since it has no concept of 'files'. There's plenty of scripting languages for pretty much every platform under the sun, e.g. perl, php, python, ruby, etc... Pick your poison and go with it.

Comment: ECMAScript has no mechanism for input or output, it is entirely reliant on a host environment for that. You may be able to use a browser by inserting the text as the content of a form control (say text area) or some other element like a div, or you may be able to use something like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). No doubt there are better solutions.